# AppleScript click on button (chrome)

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, javascript

Here is the HTML tag of the button I would like to click using AppleScript.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" autofocus="" ng-click="ok()" tabindex="0"><!-- ngIf: !isTranslate --><span ng-if="!isTranslate" class="ng-scope">OK</span><!-- end ngIf: !isTranslate --> <!-- ngIf: isTranslate --></button
```

Here is my script

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 2 of window 1 to set clickOnMyButton to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('ng-scope')[0].click();"
end tell
```

Result:

> missing value

how can I generate a click ?

Update : I found that this is causing the block

```
 style="z-index: 1050; display: block;"
```

Full HTML block

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""><div class="modal-header ng-scope"><span class="information-icon glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <!-- ngIf: !isTranslate --><span class="information-header ng-scope" ng-if="!isTranslate">Information</span><!-- end ngIf: !isTranslate --> <!-- ngIf: isTranslate --></div><div class="ng-scope"><span class="glyphicon modal-body glyphicon-menu-down" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-menu-down' : !errorDetails, 'glyphicon-menu-right' : errorDetails}" ng-click="errorDetails = !errorDetails" tabindex="0"></span><!-- ngIf: !isTranslate --><span ng-if="!isTranslate" class="ng-scope">Details</span><!-- end ngIf: !isTranslate --> <!-- ngIf: isTranslate --></div><!-- ngIf: !errorBullets --><div ng-if="!errorBullets" collapse="errorDetails" class="ng-scope collapse in" style="height: auto;"><ul><li class="ng-binding">Please provide Purchase data</li></ul></div><!-- end ngIf: !errorBullets --><!-- ngIf: errorBullets --><div class="modal-footer ng-scope"><button class="btn btn-primary" autofocus="" ng-click="ok()" tabindex="0"><!-- ngIf: !isTranslate --><span ng-if="!isTranslate" class="ng-scope">OK</span><!-- end ngIf: !isTranslate --> <!-- ngIf: isTranslate --></button></div></div></div>
</div>
```

If I can't click on the menu, how can I remove this using AppleScript?

Comment: What is the URL of then web page you're trying to interact with?

Comment: It’s an internal url unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('ng-scope')[0].click();` is perfectly fine JavaScript, but it's targeting a `<span>` element (which usually don't have `click()` events associated with them), and not the `<button>` element (whose `class` attribute has value `"btn-primary"`).

Therefore, your JavaScript needs to target `btn-primary`, like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].click();
```

(where `[0]` will possibly need to be adjusted, depending on how many other elements before this one share its class name).

Alternatively, if you're confident that the correct `<span>` element is identified by the index `0`, then you could access its parent element (which is the `<button>`) and issue the `click()` that way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ng-scope')[0].parentElement.click();
```

Without access to the webpage itself, though, I'm unable to test this rigorously, so, whilst I'm confident that the JavaScript principles are sound, you may need to do some tweaks of your own to isolate the element by using the correct class name and correct array index.

Answer (score 1):

It might be generating a click that you aren't capturing.

1. Inserted your exact markup with Chrome DevTools (to this page)
2. Added *onclick="alert('!');"* to the button
3. Ran your exact script in Script Editor
4. Got "!" alert dialog

Comment: Thank you for your answers, 
I'm not very good with JS and HTML, where should I add onclick="alert('!'); - like this : (class="ng-scope">OK</span>onclick="alert('!'); ?

Comment: Like this `<button onclick="alert('This is an alert dialog');" class="btn"></button>`