# Applescript fill up chrome textfield class

Tags: macos, applescript, google-chrome, automation, javascript-automation

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Search Cases" data-maxlength="" data-div-placeholder-content="true">mytexthere</div>
```

I don't manage to fill up the text from this textfield

here is my script :

```
set textToSave to "Demo"
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 3 of window 1 to set theTextInfo to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('search-field has-drop-down-menu component')[0].value=" & quoted form of textToSave
end tell
```

I have no error on AppleScript but no result on chrome...

Comment: Not that this will resolve the issue, however in the `tell application "Google Chrome"` _block_, the ` & ""` at the end of `tell tab 3 ...` line of _code_ servers absolutely no purpose whatsoever because you adding literally nothing `""` to the end of the _command_! It actually should be: ` & ";"`

Comment: Yes I took that from a snippet, I actually don't even remember why I have this , make no sense alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly with your question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324008/applescript-click-on-button-chrome), the issue is that you're trying to reference an HTML element by a `class` name that does not exist.

The HTML snippet you supplied contains a single `<div>` element, whose `class` attribute has the value `"content"`.  Your JavaScript uses the `getElementsByClassName()` method with the argument `'search-field has-drop-down-menu component'`, which seems to have come from nowhere.

Therefore, to explain briefly about the `getElementsByClassName()` method, it is used to search within a collection of HTML elements for all the elements that have a `class` attribute with the value you specify as the argument.  For example, `getElementsByClassName('foo')` will match `<div class="foo">...</div>`, and `<a class="foo bar">...</a>`, but it will **not** match `<p class="foobar" id="foo" name="foo">...</p>`.

To replace `mytexthere` inside the `<div>` element, you could use this method with the argument `"content"` (the class name of the `<div>` element); identify the correct index number if the method returns more than one item; then set the `textContent` property to the desired value:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('content')[2].textContent='...';
```

where `[2]` would need to be changed to the correct index number from the list of elements returned by `getElementsByClassName('content')`.

There are other JavaScript methods you can use, such as [**`querySelector()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp), which—to be useful—will require you read up on [**CSS Selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).  But, once you're familiar with these, you can perform some very powerful element queries.

Comment: Thank you, work perfectly, will have a deeper look on  querySelector(), thank for the tips.